# Use of by/in for a line graph

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference, ielts

Assuming I have to describe a line graph, which represents a trend in a past period of time and shows a declining line from A (value: 10%, year 1996) to B (value: 3%, year 2000), I could write:

> 1 After this point (A), figures decreased to 3% **in** 2000.
> 2 After this point (A), figures decreased to 3% **by** 2000.

Some part of me thinks they are both correct, but I can't avoid thinking somehow that the first line seems to lack the idea of a gradual progression towards the reached value. The mystery deepens since I have been coming across both the expressions to define the same behaviors for the line described.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

**By 2000** means from the time concerned (which you have not specified) to some (undefined) point in the year 2000.

**In 2000** means in the course of the year 2000.

The meanings are completely different.

Comment: Absolutely, i know they have different meanings, but maybe they are still both usable in this case? My thought was: if the declining line marks that value (3%) only in 2000, it is correct to say "it decreased in 2000 to 3%" (because before it was 2.9, 2.8, 2.7, and so on). But at the same time, I sense that if I write so, it can convey the idea that the decrease is not gradual, whereas I would give it better using "by".

Comment: Ronald Sole is right. If there are no other modifiers in the sentence I would go with "by 2000". If suppose the sentence was "After this point (A), figures decreased to point B at 3% in 2000.", I suppose that could be used too.

Comment: Ok I can agree, but I have found this sentence in my book for IELTS:"Following this [it was talking about 1950s trend], the number of cases dropped sharply to well below 20,000 IN the mid-1970s". It's from a description of a line graph. According to what both of you say, I would expect the use of "by".

Answer (score 0):

"**In** 2000" merely says that the figures decreased and at some point in the year 2000, they were 3%.

"**By** 2000" adds the perspective of looking forward in time, from time A to 2000. If you say something happened "by 2000", you presuppose a previous point before it happened. It fits the narrative of first describing time A and then the status at a subsequent time.

Another example:

- **In** January, vaccines were/became available. (simply describes what happened in January)
- **By** January, vaccines were/had become available. (implies that it took time to reach this milestone, and it was reached during or before January)